# How to calculate this integral when the function is unknown?

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f :[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f'(x) = \sqrt{1+f^2(x)}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. If $f(0) + f(1) = 0,$ **calculate the integral**

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you happen to remember what the derivative of the tangent function looks like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Step I) $f$ is a real valued function, thus, for all $x \in [0,1]$,
$$
1=\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}}
$$
Step II)
Evaluate the definite integral
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}}\,dx
$$

Step III) Note that the integrand is the derivative of $\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}$

Comment: Note: the above substitution shows f=f''

Comment: I've taken the liberty of better formatting your answer, that's very neat

Comment: Thanks! That was all I needed for

Comment: I left out step 3 because I wanted to see if user 180321 would remember the chain rule. It is their homework after all.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it by solving the separable differential equation $y' = \sqrt{1+y^2}$, but you could also use symmetry: show that $f(1/2 + t) + f(1/2-t) = 0$.

EDIT: Oh, the easiest way:  $$ \dfrac{d}{dx} \sqrt{1+f(x)^2} = \ldots$$

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution without differential equations, else I would have tagged "differential equations"

Comment: So use the symmetry... It's a bit strange, though, to say "a solution without differential equations", because $f'(x) = \sqrt{1+f(x)^2}$ **is** a differential equation.

Comment: I'm 100% sure it can be calculated without solving the equation, because it's an exercise from my school, thus we haven't learned differential equations. So, there must be  a different solution...

Comment: So it's a solution without **knowing about** differential equations, not a solution without differential equations.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Corey had the same answer as your “easiest way” much in advance (and he got an undeserved downvote for a correct answer, albeit with poor formatting).

Comment: @egreg I don't know what are you talking about, but I up-voted everyone's answers

Comment: @user180321 It was just a remark about the edit to the present answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the differential equation $f' = \sqrt{1 + f^2}$, we obtain the differential equation $(f')^2 - f^2 = 1$. Since $\cosh^2 (x) - \sinh^2 (x) = 1$, we look for solutions of the following form

$$f (x) = c_1 \,\mathrm{e}^{x} + c_2 \, \mathrm{e}^{-x}$$

Using $(f')^2 - f^2 = 1$, we obtain $c_1 c_2 = -\frac{1}{4}$. From $f (0) + f (1) = 0$, we obtain $c_2 = - \mathrm{e} \, c_1$.

Thus,

$$f (x) = \pm\sinh \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

which is odd-symmetric about $x = \frac{1}{2}$. Hence, $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f (x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$.